# Is it possible to type "return + shift" to insert a new line in deoplete?

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, plugin-deoplete

Here is a situation. I use deoplete but since the pop-up menu when I type in something already puts the cursor at the first item on the list, when I type in return, it inserts a new line.

So I want to type in return + shift to insert a new line (move the cursor to the next line on insert mode) and typing in just return key adds the completion target.

Is this possible? I use neovim 0.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

"return + shift" (AKA `<S-Enter>`) cannot be mapped in Nvim, unless you're using a GUI that captures "shift" and separately. But "alt + return" (`<A-Enter>`) can be mapped.

```
:inoremap <A-Enter> <C-e><Enter>
```

Comment: in Konsole and vim, shift-enter produces `^[OM`, so it's perfectly mappable using say `set <f26>=^[OM`.  `set <s-enter>` is not recognized, however.

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10 using Alacritty as a terminal I was able to map to `<S-Cr>` in **n**vim without problem using (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter/42461580#42461580). For regular Vim however I think @Mass' comment still applies.